# Python: File not exists. Make sure of the right filename

Tags: python, arguments

I am using code from one guy

```
import sys
try:
    filename = sys.argv[1];
    represent_points = int(sys.argv[2]);
    delimeter = sys.argv[3];
    if (delimeter=="space"):
        delimeter = " ";
    if (delimeter=="tab"):
        delimeter = "\t";
    f = open(filename+".txt","r");
except:
    sys.exit("File not exists. Make sure of the right filename");
from string import *
import degree_sampling
degree_sampling.degree_sampling(filename,represent_points,delimeter);
```

But

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/KSCnet_Linux/Python_Code$ python trialrun.py datan 21
File not exists. Make sure of the right filename
```

That is not true

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/KSCnet_Linux/Python_Code$ stat datan.txt
  File: ‘datan.txt’
  Size: 65          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 3670784     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ milenko)   Gid: ( 1000/ milenko)
Access: 2016-04-08 10:54:23.695416155 -0300
Modify: 2016-04-08 10:54:23.695416155 -0300
Change: 2016-04-08 10:54:23.695416155 -0300
 Birth: -
```

What should I do?

Comment: The `except` capture every exception. So it is not sure that the problem is with the file open. It may even be with `sys.argv[3]` not exists or anything. Try changing the exception

Comment: You should use `except IOError:` to specifically catch errors caused by the file not existing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python trailrun.py datan 21` has only 2 arguments but the script has:

```
delimeter = sys.argv[3]
```

If you check the error I believe that you'll see an `IndexError` because you're trying to access an index that doesn't exist in `sys.argv`. You should supply the correct amount of arguments or try to handle cases when a third argument isn't provided to the script.

Also, check out [ArgParse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). It's the Python provided API for creating command line arguments in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter pointed out could be the issue, you're missing the last parameter, the delimeter. Try:

```
python trialrun.py datan 21 space
```

Also as another commenter pointed out, to not be confused by this in the future, you should catch only the expected error. Replace this:

```
except:
```

With this:

```
except IOError:
```